# Oracle Procedure for pagination, searching and sorting

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating procedure in SqlDeveloper for pagination, searching and sorting. Below is my Procedure query and I am getting error at "OFFSET DisplayStart ROWS".

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE XX_EMS_GET_ITEM_DESC_New(
    DisplayLength INTEGER,
    DisplayStart INTEGER,
    SortCol INTEGER,
    SortDir VARCHAR2,
    SearchTxt VARCHAR2,
    result_data OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN

open sys_refcursor for
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount, Item, description        
    FROM xx_dts_item_no_v
    WHERE 
        (SearchTxt IS NULL OR 
          Item LIKE '%' || SearchTxt || '%' OR 
         Description LIKE '%' || SearchTxt || '%')
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN SortDir = 'ASC' THEN 
                CASE SortCol
                    WHEN 0 THEN Item
                    WHEN 1 THEN Description
                END 
            END desc,
        CASE 
            WHEN SortDir = 'desc' THEN 
                CASE SortCol
                    WHEN 0 THEN Item
                    WHEN 1 THEN Description
                END 
            END DESC
    OFFSET DisplayStart ROWS
    FETCH NEXT DisplayLength ROWS ONLY;
END XX_EMS_GET_ITEM_DESC_New;
```

Getting Below error while compiling procedure.

```
Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(33,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon at the end of `FETCH NEXT DisplayLength ROWS ONLY`

Comment: added semi-colon just after FETCH NEXT DisplayLength ROWS ONLY and now Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(33,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended showing

Comment: Concatenation operator - in Oracle - is double pipe `||`, not `+`.

Comment: Also, in PL/SQL, a SELECT requires an INTO clause (your code is missing it).

Comment: I have all the above changes but still same error

Comment: Please check updated code in above question

Comment: Should be `open result_data for`